# Traversing up the DOM to show the individual content according to each anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

Im working on an some code to fade toggle information out of its relevant link. Because i want to show the content so it doesn't hide the anchor. Does anyone know if there is a way to go up the DOM and show the individual content according to each anchor? My code shows that its going up the DOM. I'm struggling to get it working using the jsfiddle code below.

http://jsfiddle.net/g1mn79td/

```
<div class="info">
    <p>South Korea</p>
    <p>South Korea is known globally for its thriving energy industry, providing a large number of overseas employment opportunities. The majority of foreign nationals make themselves at home in the larger cities such as Seoul, Busan and Incheon. If you’ve found a great role in South Korea, then follow the link to find out more about what you’ll need to think about when moving yourself or your family to this fascinating country.</p>
</div>
<div class="info">
    <p>Angola</p>
    <p>As one of the largest countries in southern Africa, Angola has great natural resources in oil, diamonds, gold and copper. Portuguese is the most commonly spoken language in Angola so learning some of the basics can be instrumental in helping you get by. The prospect of moving yourself and even your family to a new country can be overwhelming with many elements to think about when planning your relocation. All of this information and more is available in this guide.</p>
</div>
<div class="t">
    <div class="tc rel">
        <div class="book" id="book">
            <div class="page cover"></div>
            <div class="page two">
                <div class="block">
                     <h1>passport</h1>
                     <a href="https://github.com/blasten/turn.js" class="tip">click</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="page three">
                <div class="block">
                     <h1>passport</h1>
 <a href="https://github.com/blasten/turn.js">click</a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background-color: #333;
}
body.hide-overflow {
    overflow: hidden;
}
/* helpers */
 .t {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.tc {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
.rel {
    position: relative;
}
/* book */
 .book {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 140px;
}
.book .page {
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.book .cover {
    background:white url(pages/1.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
.book .two {
    background:url(pages/2.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
.book .three {
    background:url(pages/3.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
.book .page img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.block {
    background:red;
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    display:block;
    margin:60px auto;
    padding:10%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.green {
    background:green;
}
body .info {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
    height: auto;
    margin: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 80%;
    z-index: 1;
    display:none;
    padding:10px
}
body .info p {
    font-size:15px;
    line-height:20px
}
```

```js
var $findtip = $('.page');

$findtip.find('a').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function () {
    var $link = $(this);
    $(this).parents().eq(7).find('.info').fadeToggle();

});
```

Comment: I also tried using this code, but it's still not working:-                                 var $findtip = $('.page a');

$findtip.on('mouseenter mouseleave', function () {
 var order = $(this).parent().parent().get();
 console.log(order);
 //$('.info').eq(order).fadeToggle();
    
});

Comment: To go up the parent chain to a specific selector for a parent, use `.closest(selector)`.  For example, `$(this).closest("ul")` would find your parent `<ul>` tag when an `<li>` was clicked on.  Or `$(this).closest("table")` would find your parent `<table>` element no matter where inside the table you started.

Comment: Apologies, the correct fiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/g1mn79td/4/    
The problem i have is targeting the .info divs according to each anchor. One is for Angola and one is for korea. Currently they both show Angola.

Comment: There is not a one-to-one correspondence between anchors and items with `class="info"` so we can't really tell what exactly you're trying to find from any given anchor.  You will need to describe what you're trying to accomplish in more specifics to know how to help.

Comment: When i mouseover the 'click' anchor on the left, it should show a white box with 'South Korea' information inside. And when i mouseover the 'click' anchor on the right i want it to show 'Angola' information in the white box. If possible.

Comment: This is the correct fiddle:-
http://jsfiddle.net/g1mn79td/4/

Comment: Please use the "edit" link under your question to correct the jsFiddle link in your question so people don't go looking at the wrong jsFiddle link.  You can always correct or add to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/g1mn79td/6/

```
var o;
$('.page a').on('mouseenter mouseleave',function(){
    o = $(this).parent().parent().index();
    i = parseInt(o) - 1;
    $('body').find('.info').eq(i).fadeToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no direct structural connection between a given link and a given `info` section (e.g. they are not each uniquely in a sub-tree of the DOM), you will have to create such a link.  I'd suggest adding an id to each info section:

```
<div id="koreaInfo" class="info">
    <p>South Korea</p>
    <p>South Korea is known globally for its thriving energy industry, providing a large number of overseas employment opportunities. The majority of foreign nationals make themselves at home in the larger cities such as Seoul, Busan and Incheon. If you’ve found a great role in South Korea, then follow the link to find out more about what you’ll need to think about when moving yourself or your family to this fascinating country.</p>
</div>
<div id="angolaInfo" class="info">
    <p>Angola</p>
    <p>As one of the largest countries in southern Africa, Angola has great natural resources in oil, diamonds, gold and copper. Portuguese is the most commonly spoken language in Angola so learning some of the basics can be instrumental in helping you get by. The prospect of moving yourself and even your family to a new country can be overwhelming with many elements to think about when planning your relocation. All of this information and more is available in this guide.</p>
</div>
```

And, the add a custom attribute to each link:

```
<a href="https://github.com/blasten/turn.js" class="tip" data-info="koreaInfo">click</a>
....
<a href="https://github.com/blasten/turn.js" class="tip" data-info="angolaInfo">click</a>
```

The, you can fetch the custom attribute for the hovered link and use that to show/hide the relevant info area.

```
$(".tip").hover(function() {
    $(".info").hide();
    var id = $(this).data("info");
    $("#" + id).show();
}, function() {
    $(".info").hide();
});
```